# wp_localize_script is not passing data to my JS frontend

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have done this before but for some reason its dying now. Why? My plugin's index.php has:

```
add_shortcode('idealformNG', 'func_idealform');
function func_idealform($attr)
{
    $args = shortcode_atts( array(
        'pageid' => '',
    ), $attr );

    // ----- enqueue required assets ----->>

    wp_enqueue_style('styles', plugins_url('public/css/styles.css', __FILE__));
    wp_enqueue_script('cookie', 'public/js/js.cookie.min.js', [], '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('serialize', 'public/js/jquery.serializejson.js', [], '1.0', true);
    
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_assets');
    function enqueue_assets($args)
    {
        global $post;
        if($post->ID === intval($args['pageid']))
        {
            wp_localize_script( 'styles', 'cookie', 'serialize', 'ng_data', array(
                'builderURL'        => 'http://google.com',
            ) );
            
        }
    }
    enqueue_assets($args);
    // ----- /enqueue required assets ----->>
}
```

and in my plugin JS I simply have:

```
console.log(ng_data.builderURL);
```

which errs as: Uncaught ReferenceError: ng_data is not defined.

Any ideas why anyone?